# Python Pandas Melt 2 rows header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to melt data having multiple headers. My datafreame is

```
              |       Actual    |     Forecast    |
CID | CName    | Jan-19 | Feb-19 | Jan-20 | Feb-20 |
#1  | James    |   200  | 300    |   400  |   500  |
#2  | Fames    |   600  | 700    |   800  |   900  |
#3  | Somty    |   200  | 300    |   400  |   500  |
```

and I want the following output

```
|  CID  | CNAME | MONTH   | VALUE |   TYPE    |
|  #1   | James | Jan-19  |   200 |  Actual   |
|  #1   | James | Feb-19  |   300 |  Actual   |
|  #1   | James | Jan-20  |   400 |  Forecast |
|  #1   | James | Feb-20  |   500 |  Forecast |
|  #2   | Fames | Jan-19  |   600 |  Actual   |
|  #2   | Fames | Feb-19  |   700 |  Actual   |
|  #2   | Fames | Jan-20  |   800 |  Forecast |
|  #2   | Fames | Feb-20  |   900 |  Forecast |
|  #3   | Somty | Jan-19  |   200 |  Actual   |
|  #3   | Somty | Feb-19  |   300 |  Actual   |
|  #3   | Somty | Jan-20  |   400 |  Forecast |
|  #3   | Somty | Feb-20  |   500 |  Forecast |
```

I am able to melt data with single row header using

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['CID', 'CNAME'], value_vars=['Jan-19', 'Feb-19'])
df
```

which works, but spend a alot of times with double row header with required output, but not found any relevant solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df=df.stack([0,1]).reset_index()
```

Comment: Appritiated for your quick response @Yoben, I tried it but getting error
Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

Comment: @DR can you print df.columns  ?

Comment: df.columns showing 

Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Actual', 'Actual.1', 'Forecast',
       'Forecast.1'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: @DRJerry you do not have multiple index in column

Comment: you mean there is issue with file format? Any suggestions, how to handle that?

Comment: No..it's a excel file and reading with -  pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

Comment: @DRJerry `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 
                   header=[0,1], 
                   index_col=[0,1], 
                   sheetname="your sheet")`

Comment: Is there any best way to remove empty rows and columns? I am checking if string contains any empty value then remove it as follow but it is removing entire rows either only one of the cell is empty.

columns = dataframe.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')
dataframe = dataframe.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
new_header = dataframe.iloc[0]
dataframe = dataframe[1:]
dataframe.columns = new_header

Answer (score 0):

It works good with 2 columns using following code.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, encoding="ISO-8859-1", header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1])
df = df.stack([0, 1]).reset_index()
```

But if I add one more column like Region in this example

```
                       |       Actual    |     Forecast    |
CID | CName | Region   | Jan-19 | Feb-19 | Jan-20 | Feb-20 |
#1  | James |   US     |   200  | 300    |   400  |   500  |
#2  | Fames |   IND    |   600  | 700    |   800  |   900  |
#3  | Somty |   CA     |   200  | 300    |   400  |   500  |
```

It return following results

```
    level_0|  level_1|  level_2 | CNAME     | 0
0   | #1  | James  |  Actual    | Feb-19    | 300
1   | #1  | James  |  Actual    | Jan-19    | 200
2   | #1  | James  |  Forecast  | Feb-20    | 500
3   | #1  | James  |  Forecast  | Jan-20    | 400
4   | #1  | James  |  Unnamed:  | 2_level_0 | Region   US
5   | #2  | Fames  |  Actual    | Feb-19    | 700
6   | #2  | Fames  |  Actual    | Jan-19    | 600
7   | #2  | Fames  |  Forecast  | Feb-20    | 900
8   | #2  | Fames  |  Forecast  | Jan-20    | 800
9   | #2  | Fames  |  Unnamed:  | 2_level_0 | Region   IND
10  | #3  | Somty  |  Actual    | Feb-19    | 300
11  | #3  | Somty  |  Actual    | Jan-19    | 200
12  | #3  | Somty  |  Forecast  | Feb-20    | 500
13  | #3  | Somty  |  Forecast  | Jan-20    | 400
14  | #3  | Somty  |  Unnamed:  | 2_level_0 | Region   CA
```

But I need

```
    level_0 | Region |  level_1   | level_2  |   CNAME  |   0
0   | #1    |  US    |  James   |   Actual   |  Feb-19  | 300.0
1   | #1    |  US    |  James   |   Actual   |  Jan-19  | 200.0
2   | #1    |  US    |  James   |   Forecast |  Feb-20  | 500.0
3   | #1    |  US    |  James   |   Forecast |  Jan-20  | 400.0
4   | #2    |  US    |  Fames   |   Actual   |  Feb-19  | 700.0
5   | #2    |  US    |  Fames   |   Actual   |  Jan-19  | 600.0
6   | #2    |  US    |  Fames   |   Forecast |  Feb-20  | 900.0
7   | #2    |  US    |  Fames   |   Forecast |  Jan-20  | 800.0
8   | #3    |  US    |  Somty   |   Actual   |  Feb-19  | 300.0
9   | #3    |  US    |  Somty   |   Actual   |  Jan-19  | 200.0
10  | #3    |  US    |  Somty   |   Forecast |  Feb-20  | 500.0
11  | #3    |  US    |  Somty   |   Forecast |  Jan-20  | 400.0
```

Comment: @YOBEN_S, do you have any idea on that?